# How can I summarize a data frame in a "long" format by multiple columns?

Tags: r, plyr

I have a dataframe organized as follows:

```
Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Variable 3 | Outcome Variable
---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------------
Factor     | Factor     | Factor     | Outcome
```

for a few thousand rows, 15 variable columns, and 1 output column. I would like to summarize the table (preferably using plyr) in the following long format:

```
Variable 1 | Variable 2 | Variable 3 | Outcome Variable
---------- | ---------- | ---------- | ----------------
Factor 1   | Factor 1   | Factor 1   | Average Outcome 
Factor 1   | Factor 1   | Factor 2   | Average Outcome 
Factor 1   | Factor 2   | Factor 1   | Average Outcome 
Factor 1   | Factor 2   | Factor 2   | Average Outcome
```

for different variable combinations.  What is the easiest way to do this?

Comment: You can use aggregate in base R. `aggregate(outcome ~ fac1 + fac2 + fac3, data=dat, FUN=mean)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(variable1, variable2, variable3) %>%
    summarise(OutcomeVariable = mean(OutcomeVariable))
```

---

Or with `base R`

```
aggregate(OutcomeVariable ~., df1, FUN = mean)
```